# How to sum the values by key in pyspark sql or Mysql

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

***I don't know how to add the values by index help me with this: Add the values according to the index of the values of the Key***

**The input CSV:**

```
Country,Values
Canada,47;97;33;94;6
Canada,59;98;24;83;3
Canada,77;63;93;86;62
China,86;71;72;23;27
China,74;69;72;93;7
China,58;99;90;93;41
England,40;13;85;75;90
England,39;13;33;29;14
England,99;88;57;69;49
Germany,67;93;90;57;3
Germany,0;9;15;20;19
Germany,77;64;46;95;48
India,90;49;91;14;70
India,70;83;38;27;16
India,86;21;19;59;4
```

**The output csv Should be:**

```
Country,Values
Canada,183;258;150;263;71
China,218;239;234;209;75
England,178;114;175;173;153
Germany,144;166;151;172;70
India,246;153;148;100;90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Import required modules & create session

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

> Read csv file & create view

```
file_df = spark_session.read.csv("/data/user/country_values.csv",header=True)

temp_view = file_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")
```

> Write sql query

```
output_df = spark_session.sql("select country, concat( cast (sum (split(values,';') [0]) as int),';', cast (sum (split(Values,';')[1]) as int),';',cast(sum(split(values,';')[2]) as int),';', cast (sum (split(Values,';')[3]) as int),';', cast(sum (split(values,';')[4]) as int)) as values from temp_view group by Country order by country")
```

> print result

```
output_df.show()
```

Limitations -> SQL query has been written in a way that Values column should have 5 values after splitting with ";" delimiter. Values column is being split 5 times in query, it can be optimized.

Or use CTE to split the Values into an array of integers before the main aggregation:

```
spark_session.sql(""" 

    WITH t1 AS ( 
        SELECT Country
        ,      CAST(split(Values, ";") AS array<int>) AS V
        FROM temp_view 
    )   
    SELECT Country 
    ,      CONCAT_WS(";", sum(V[0]), sum(V[1]), sum(V[2]), sum(V[3]), sum(V[4])) AS Values 
    FROM t1 
    GROUP BY Country 
    ORDER BY Country

  """).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: use CTE to split the field into an array.

Comment: @DiwakarKumar Its working for me, whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: @Ravi it's working ........can we optimise it because  here we have to split it for several time .....and please give me a good reference of book to learn mysql or spark SQL....thanks

Comment: @jxc can you tell me how to use CTE to split the field into an array.

Comment: @Ravi, do you mind I add this into your post, it's a little long to fit into the comment.

Comment: @DiwakarKumar,@Ravi: I added an Spark SQL using CTE at the end of your post, please check and modify it if needed. have a good weekend..

Comment: @jxc is there any way to use while loop to sum the values without using it separately...

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, since the SQL is a string, you can always construct the SQL expression separately. if you know the number of items in the array, then:  `'CONCAT_WS(";", {}) AS Values'.format(','.join([ 'sum(V[{}])'.format(i) for i in range(5)]))`, this is for one field only, you can extend this to the whole SQL statement.